# ++a and a-- output the second always as same as the forward one in C code

Tags: c

Well my English not very good and I am a beginner of C pls don't mind.Here's the questions , when I put in ++a and a-- at the same program ,the second always read the forward one , can someone help me to figure it out im
will appreciate it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

   int a = 8;

   printf("a=%d\n", ++a);
   printf("a=%d\n", a--);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

it output
a=9 a=9

Comment: `++a` increments `a` and then returns the value so the first output is `9` while `a--` will return the value of `a` first and then decrement it, so you still get `9` as the second output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of the increment or decrement operator (before or after) changes the semantics of the operation.

For the pre-increment and -decrement operator, the result is the new value (after increment or decrement).

For the post-increment and -decrement, the result is the *old* value (before the increment or decrement).

That means e.g.

```
printf("a=%d\n", a--);
```

is equivalent to:

```
{
    int old_value = a;
    a = a - 1;
    printf("a=%d\n", old_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That’s correct. The first `printf` pre-increments to 9 and then prints that. The second evaluates the 9, prints it, and then post-decrements.

Answer (score 0):

`++a` increments `a` first before printing. `a--` prints `a` first before decrementing.